# Karate: is there a way to add implicit wait similar to other frameworks

Tags: api, karate

In the UI automation using karate drive and robot concept, due to application slowness need to provide delay/sleep in between steps.

where the time duration are not same, so can we set implicit wait time across the scenarios in background or in karate-config?

Comment: first, there is no such thing as "implicit wait" in karate. please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core#retry-defaults - if that doesn't make sense, I think you should look for another framework